# AngularJS: Link element to controller in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive `<my-configform></my-configform>` in which I get a JSON array from an API during the compile stage and dynamically construct the element's DOM from:

```
angular.module('mymodule').directive('myConfigform', function($http, $compile, $interpolate) {
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: 'ConfigCtrl', // Added as per Craig's suggestion
  compile: function(element) {
    var buildMyForm = function(data) {
      var template = $interpolate('<form role="form">{{form}}</form>');
      var formMarkup;
      // ... build formMarkup from data ...
      // just as a very simple example what it could look like:
      formMarkup = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="config.ticked"> Tick me';

      return template({form: formMarkup});
    };
    $http.get('/api/some/endpoint').success(function(data) {
      element.replaceWith(buildMyForm());
    });
  }
});
```

My problem is that the form is not bound to the controller after compilation. The elements are all in the DOM, <strike>but the `ConfigCtrl` controller is not created and</strike> no data binding has taken place.
How can I tell Angular to bind the controller to my dynamically created form?

Comment: Have you tried adding the controller attribute to your directive definition?  (e.g. controller: 'ConfigCtrl') Or did you use ng-controller at a higher level in your DOM?

Comment: Adding the controller attribute helped insofar as my `ConfigCtrl` is now instantiated, but there is still no data-binding between the elements in the form and their respective models in the controller scope.

Comment: Can you make a Plunker to show the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile the generated html inside the post linking function like below:

```
.directive('myConfigform', function($http, $compile, $interpolate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(element) {
        var buildMyForm = function(data) {
          var template = $interpolate('<form role="form">{{form}}</form>');
          var formMarkup = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="config.ticked"> Tick me';
          return template({form: formMarkup});
        };
        element.replaceWith(buildMyForm());
        return function(scope, element) {
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/722skf?p=preview)